# Where is this line of code calling this method from?

Tags: php, javascript, modx, modx-evolution

I am trying to deduce why this method in my href *does not work*. It returns a javascript error :

```
<form name="mutate" method="post" action="index.php?a=24">
  <a href="#" onclick="documentDirty=false; document.mutate.save.click();saveWait('mutate');">
```

The error is `document.mutate.save is undefined`

Fair enough. But I want to figure out why, and then define it.

What is the best way for me to trace the source of this error?

Comment: show your javascript pls

Comment: I think a lot more code is needed to answer this question, since `document.mutate` isn't exactly BOM-standard.

Comment: Seems like you're using [MODX](http://www.modx.com/). [This thread](http://forums.modx.com/thread/32982/javscript-error-of-quot-document-mutate-save-is-undefined-quot) suggests you have upgraded it and the upgrade went wrong. [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com/search?q=document.mutate.save+is+undefined)...

Comment: @Dave , yah I saw that thread and commented at the bottom of it.

Comment: @LaurenceBurke There's quite a few javascript files that ModX uses. I'm not exactly sure what I should even be looking for..

Comment: @Neal indeed, although LMGTFY is very, very, very frowned upon here (as is JFGI)

Comment: @DaveRandom Im am not sure that is true.

Comment: @Neal I say that because I posted one once and was showered with a hate storm from all sides...

Comment: What snippet you use? i never saw form like that in Modx Evo. Or do you mean you're editing the back end manager?

Answer (score 0):

`document.mutate` refers to the form element you are working in (`<form name="mutate"...>`)

I'd assume that `document.mutate.save` refers to a button named save somewhere in the form.

The error is telling you that the button does not exist.

Comment: Sure, thank you. Isn't that technically what I have written in my question?

Comment: Well, it seemed as though you didn't know what was causing the error. I also didn't notice the `modx` tag however, so given that you're using a CMS all bets are off as to where the HTML is generated for that button.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I do know where the file is that is creating that button. I have that located. document(is raw js).mutate( is something that ModX is responsible for.. ). So I assume that what is occuring here is `.mutate` is not being defined and frontloaded properly. ModX uses mooTools, but I checked the mootools and this isn't a function. So I assume its Modx..and I can't find any definition of it anywhere in any of the files..